# Box2D sleep time

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I was just wondering if there was a way to change the amount of time until the sleep state is activated for a body in box2d (cocos2d).

I currently use the sleep state as a way to end a game so it is preferable if I can speed up the time it takes to achieve the sleep state.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A physics engine doesn't put objects to sleep based on time. It only puts bodies to sleep which are at rest (idle). Typically the physics engine defines rules when it's safe to put a body to sleep, normally that's when the body has stopped moving at all, when there are no other moving bodies touching it, and when both conditions are met for a certain period of time.

In Box2D you can't modify this behavior unless you modify the Box2D source code (not recommended). In Chipmunk you can at least set the threshold for how long a body must be idle before it is put to sleep. Changing this value can sometimes lead to the effect that slow moving objects will suddenly fall to sleep.

To implement the behavior you want, you should define your own set of rules. Iterate over all bodies that may be moving slowly at the end of the game. Get the values for angular rotation and velocity, and check if they have fallen below a certain threshold that feels good for your game. Then end the game, or you can also manually put the object to sleep with body->SetAwake(false).